# Are Ilvermorny and the Salem Witches Institute supposed to be the same school?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

I read that Ilvermorny is in Massachusetts. In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Ron and Harry meet people from the Salem Witches' Institute at the Quidditch World Cup. Are Ilvermorny and the Salem Witches' Institute supposed to be the same school?

Answer (score 10):

**No**

The [Salem Witches Institute](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Salem_Witches%27_Institute) isn't one of the [eleven wizarding schools](https://www.pottermore.com/collection/wizarding-schools)

It's a joke reference to a UK organization, as stated by JK herself (2015):

> "The Salem Witches' Institute isn't a school, but a joke on the
>   Women's Institute in the UK."

-https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/607275327111458816

Additionally, in the book, the members are described as:

> "a group of middle-aged American witches [sitting] gossipping happily beneath a star-spangled banner stretched between their tents"

So, they are clearly not students.

As to what the [Women's Institute](https://www.thewi.org.uk/about-the-wi) is (and by extension, what we may imagine the SWI would say it does):

> The Women's Institute (WI) was formed in 1915 to revitalise rural
>   communities and encourage women to become more involved in producing
>   food during the First World War. Since then the organisation's aims
>   have broadened and the WI is now the largest voluntary women's
>   organisation in the UK. The WI celebrated its centenary in 2015 and
>   currently has almost 220,000 members in approximately 6,300 WIs.
>
> The WI plays a unique role in providing women with educational
>   opportunities and the chance to build new skills, to take part in a
>   wide variety of activities and to campaign on issues that matter to
>   them and their communities.

Comment: Based off the quote from the book alone, they might be alumni or faculty.

Comment: the answer is it isn't a school. More detail isn't needed to clearly and precisely answer the question as asked - especially with a word of god statement as the answer :) - but I'll add some info

Answer (score 9):

## Definitely not.

NKCampbell's answer already gives the information that the Salem Witches' Institute wasn't a school, but there are a few other things that make it even clearer that Ilvermorny certainly isn't the Salem Witches' Institute.

**Ilvermorny isn't in Salem.**

Ilvermorny is on the summit of Mount Greylock, which is on the *opposite* side of Massachusetts from Salem.

[image: Massachusetts]

The star shows where Mount Greylock is, and Salem is clearly labeled, and on the opposite side of the state.

**Additionally, Ilvermorny isn't for witches only.**

Ilvermorny isn't a girls-only school: both witches and wizards attend.

> Now witch and wizard children from all over North America were being sent to learn there and it became a boarding school. By the nineteenth century, Ilvermorny had gained the international reputation it enjoys today. <sub><sup>- Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry - Pottermore</sup></sub>

The reason Isolt Sayre began a school was to teach her adoptive sons magic. Both of them, as well as her Muggle husband James, each named one of the Houses in Ilvermorny. Given this origin, it would be unusual for a school founded to teach two young wizards later became an all-witches school.

**The Salem Witches' Institute isn't in anything written about Ilvermorny or *Fantastic Beasts*.**

Nothing released to promote *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* mentioned the Salem Witches' Institute, and it's never mentioned in the movie itself either. None of the additional information about wizarding society in America even mentioned them, whether in relation to Ilvermorny or in any other context.

There is the New Salem Philanthropic Society, also known as the Second Salemers, but they're certainly not a society for witches - they're trying to cause new Salem Witch Trials, and are fervently against magic.

Comment: Answer needs more hand-drawn red circles...

Comment: @TheDarkLord I've added them in! :D